# Trying to make a function that tells if he/she is the right age

Tags: function, if-statement

What's wrong with this code? It displays "you're the right age" no matter what I enter as age. It seems to me that it could be some error with the "OR"/|| ?

```js
enter code here

function AgeFunction()  {

    let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    let answer = "";

    if (age >=20 || age <=30) {
        answer += "You're the right age";
    }
    else    {   
        answer += "You're not the right age";

    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the age must be in the range [20, 30] then "AND"/&& must be used instead of "OR"/||

```
let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
let answer = "";

if (age >=20 && age <=30) {
    answer += "You're the right age";
}
else    {   
    answer += "You're not the right age";

}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = answer
```